# Company Cloud Where I Can Assign Files To A User

Tags: php, mysql, cloud, hosting

I'm looking for a script/solution for my company. Basically a place to store our contracts/invoices for our clients online (so it will be hosted on our web servers), giving our clients access to our portal at any time.

I have found many options online, however they dont allow you to assign them to a specific client folder.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[ProjectSend](http://code.google.com/p/clients-oriented-ftp/) (formerly "Clients Oriented FTP"), a PHP/MySQL application, does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. I have been testing Projectsend. I going to wait and see if there are any more suggestions :) Thanks again

Comment: @DavidMurray Sure thing!

Comment: Just one issue I found with ProjectSend. I cant create client folders. For example, if I upload a contract, I would like it to go into a folder for the client called Contracts.

Comment: Huh. That's what I get for recommending something I haven't tried, I suppose.